# highcharts change smoothing setting on polar areaspline chart

Tags: highcharts

is there any way to change the smoothing setting via config ?

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/parts-more/Polar.ts

line 190.

Or do I have to override some functions ? for info - I'm trying to change the interpolation and have got this far. If there is a better way to change the interpolation that would be an acceptable solution.

The problem I am trying to solve is where the interpolated area chart curves actually plot outside of the radar chart because the curvature is too large (ie when every value is at its maximum)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to change this value via the config. You can report this idea here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues - if core developers will see that this feature is needed they will implement it in the future.

For now, as a workaround, you can overwrite the whole function as a function with changed value.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j362zfpq/

```
 Highcharts.Series.prototype.getConnectors = function(segment, index, calculateNeighbours, connectEnds) {
          var i, prevPointInd, nextPointInd, previousPoint, nextPoint, previousX, previousY, nextX, nextY, plotX, plotY, ret,
            // 1 means control points midway between points, 2 means 1/3 from
            // the point, 3 is 1/4 etc;
            smoothing = 1,
            denom = smoothing + 1,
            leftContX, leftContY, rightContX, rightContY, dLControlPoint, // distance left control point
            dRControlPoint, leftContAngle, rightContAngle, jointAngle, addedNumber = connectEnds ? 1 : 0;
    ....
    }
```